# Dereferencing a function pointer, C++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

what's the difference between the second and third line:

```cpp
int (*myFunction)() = fooFunction;
(*fooFunction)();
fooFunction();
```

Why do both do the same thing? Is it just how C++'s syntax is? I thought that a function  pointer needs to be dereferenced in order to call it. How does the third line work, it isn't dereferenced.

Comment: You may ask a similar question about `int (*myFunction)() = fooFunction;` and `int (*myFunction)() = &fooFunction;`: *I thought that an address of a function needs to be taken in order to get a function pointer.*

Comment: You can also write `int (*myFunction)() = &&&&fooFunction;`. A pointer-to-function remains a pointer-to-function regardless of what you do to it.